# What am I missing with this PIC 12F675 configuration?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I can't manage to get GP4 as digital output (even GP2 doesn't setup as GPIO, so might it be an analog pin configuration problem?)
I should have disabled all the features but the TRIS register, on GP4 and GP2, but it doesn't seem so...

This is the code (don't mind too much if the analog acquisition is right, because I'm working on it and I'm still learning; don't mind even the comments that are in italian):

```
// PIC12F675 Configuration Bit Settings // 'C' source line config statements // 

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on GP4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on GP5/OSC1/CLKIN) 
#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled) 
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-Up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled) 
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF // GP3/MCLR pin function select (GP3/MCLR pin function is GP3) 
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD enabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Code Protection bit (Program Memory code protection is disabled) 
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled) 

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000 
#include <xc.h> 

/* ADCON serve, tra l'altro a selezionare il canale analogico da convertire in digitale * e, quindi, se si hanno piu' canali in un ciclo, da convertire, bisogna agire sempre * su questo registro */

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
unsigned short int A = 0;

void main(void) { 
    OSCCAL= 0x80; 
    CMCON = 0b00000111; 
    T1CON = 0b00000100; 
    OPTION_REG = 0b11000000; 

    // TRISIO = 0b001011;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO0 = 1;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 1;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 0;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO3 = 1;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 0; 

    ADCON0 = 0x00; 
    ANSEL = 0b00000011; // analog and digital channel selection 

    while(1) { 

        ADCON0 = 0b10000011; // select channel and start AD conversion cycle 
        __delay_ms(10); 

        A = ((ADRESH <<8)+ ADRESL);

        for(i=10;i>=0;i--) { // controlla i singoli bit 

            j = A >> i; 
            if (j & 1) { // se = 1, manda un segnale sul canale GP5
                GPIObits.GP5 = 1; 
                __delay_ms(250);
                GPIObits.GP5 = 0; 
                __delay_ms(250); 
            } 

            if (j & 0) { // se = 1, manda un segnale sul canale GP4
                GPIObits.GP4 = 1; __delay_ms(250);
                GPIObits.GP4 = 0; __delay_ms(250);
            }

            __delay_ms(1000); 

        } 
    }

    return; 
}
```

Comment: One thing missing here is *indentation* to help make this code more readable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied it from a text file I sent on my smartphone and all the indentation got lost.

Comment: I managed it a bit, but it's not easy from mobile

Comment: Looks a lot better now so we can see what's going on at least.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure you have anything wrong with your outputs, double checked and they look to be configured correctly.

I am a little baffled by the if statement :

```
if (j & 0) { // se = 1, manda un segnale sul canale GP4
                GPIObits.GP4 = 1; __delay_ms(250);
                GPIObits.GP4 = 0; __delay_ms(250);
            }
```

This if statement is doing a bitwise AND of 0 AND j, which is ALWAYS 100% guaranteed to be 0 so GP4 will never ever toggle and you may just as well remove this code.

I think this is why GP4 is not working

---

Also take a look at https://www.microforum.cc/ - a great resource for information on PIC and AVR microcontrollers and embedded programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

@Michele Giglio,

The intent of the code you posted appears to one where the ADC result is tested from the most significant bit to the least significant bit. For each bit that is a one a pulse is output on GP5, for each bit that is a zero a pulse is output on GP4.

This is your while loop modified to perform as described:

```
while(1) { 

    ADCON0 = 0b10000011; // select channel and start AD conversion cycle 
    __delay_ms(10); 

    A = ((ADRESH <<8)+ ADRESL);

    for(i=(1<<9);i!=0;i>>=1) { // controlla i singoli bit 

        if ((j & i) == 1) { // se = 1, manda un segnale sul canale GP5
            GPIObits.GP5 = 1; 
            __delay_ms(250);
            GPIObits.GP5 = 0; 
            __delay_ms(250); 
        } 

        if ((j & i) == 0) { // se = 1, manda un segnale sul canale GP4
            GPIObits.GP4 = 1;
            __delay_ms(250);
            GPIObits.GP4 = 0;
            __delay_ms(250);
        }

        __delay_ms(1000); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I managed to solve it yet :). At first I tested the Gpio with another simple program I made, and so I got that the problem was in the loop. So I modified it and now it works :)